# Visual Studio 2013 Click Once Deployment

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, dll, clickonce

I have a click once deployment project that has been working fine for a long time now.  I added some new dll's to a project that is referenced by it.  The dll's can't be referenced  in references, so I added them as files to the project.

Build Action is Content, copy to output directory is copy always.

when I build the application, the dll's appear in the bin\debug directory.  The program uses them just fine too on my computer.  When I deploy the application, the dll's don't make it to the other computer.

Under Publish in application properties I went to application files.  the dll's I need are not listed there to be included in the deployment.

I would love some help, I feel like I'm missing something really simple.

I have a feeling if I put the dll's in the main project, it would work.  I don't really want to do this, I would like to keep them all located in the project they are actually used in.

Comment: Why do you say the DLLs can't be referenced in references? You can't browse to them and add them that way?

Comment: It gives me an error. says it's not a valid assembly or com component. These dll's are not used by my application, but by the 3rd party application.  I dont know anything about them, just that they have to be in the bin directory or gac.  I don't want to do gac so that's not an option.  I've used anther api from this company, and it had a dll that was similar to these new ones, and it works in the application files just fine.  This new api just has 2 more dll's and they dont' work.

Comment: Do you mean when you try to add the reference, you get that err msg? If so, have you binged or googled that specific err msg (including the name of the DLL)?

Comment: which .NET version are you targeting? I wonder if those DLLs are built for a different version than the one you're currently targeting and that's why you can't add them as references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I deploy the application, the dll's don't make it to the other computer.
>
> ...
>
> Under Publish in application properties I went to application files. the dll's I need are not listed there to be included in the deployment.

You need to set them to download with the application.  Click the DLL in the project properties, then press F4.  Set the Build Action to Content, and the Copy to Output Directory to something like 'Copy if newer'

[image]

For information - it is likely if you download the DLLs for referencing by a built exe (for example) you may need to configure a manifest file for the executable as well to get it to pick up the DLLS correctly